# Avoid resetting of position xslt

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, xsd

For each group I have to group by artists having the same number. In the output I have to show the position of the for-each-group (output: 1, 2, 3) but the position resets when entering the second loop of the group and the output currently is (wrong-output:1,2,1).

```html
<xsl:for-each select="group"> <xsl:for-each-group select="artist" group-by="number"> <position> <xsl:value of select="position()"/> </position> <counter> <xsl:value of select="count(number)"/></counter> </xsl:for-each-group> </xsl:for-each>
```

```
or
```

```html
<xsl:for-each select="group"> <xsl:for-each-group select="artist" group-by="number"> <position> <xsl:value of select="position()"/> </position> <counter> <xsl:value of select="count(number)"/></counter> </xsl:for-each-group> </xsl:for-each>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<group>
  <artist>
    <number>1</number>
  </artist>
  <artist>
    <number>1</number>
  </artist>
  <artist>
    <number>2</number>
  </artist>
  <artist>
    <number>2</number>
  </artist>
</group>
<group>
  <artist>
    <number>5</number>
  </artist>
  <artist>
    <number>5</number>
  </artist>
</group>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show (1)a  well-formed input and (2) the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds, based on the wanted output, that you don't need and want the outer `for-each` and instead directly want to group all `artist`s with e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="group/artist" group-by="number">
```

For your sample data, that would give three groups and the inner `<xsl:value of select="position()"/>` would that way output the sequence 1, 2, 3.

With XSLT 2 or 3 you could temporarily store the differents groups, e.g. in XSLT 3 as a sequence of maps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="groups" as="map(*)*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="group">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="artist" group-by="number">
        <xsl:sequence select="map:entry(current-grouping-key(), current-group())"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]">
    <group position="{position()}" number-count="{count(?*/number)}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qjt5Re

Comment: Yes that is right , but I need the outer loop in fact. Do you think there is a way in order to keep both loops? @martin

Comment: @teall Please explain why you need (or think you need) the outer`xsl: for-each`.

Comment: For the same input , I have to apply other functions inside the for-each-group . So for example: I have to count <number> nodes for the current invoice group. If I remove the for each it will count the <number> nodes of all the invoice-groups. @michael.hor257k

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and add **all** the necessary information there.

Comment: The `<counter> <xsl:value of select="count(number)"/></counter>` would output 1 with both your approaches and the posted approach as it counts the `number` child elements of the first item in each group and all your `artist` elements have one `number` child only. As for more approaches, which version of XSLT do you use? Somehow it sounds as if you might want to store the various groups in an intermediary result. With XSLT 3 you could use a variable with a sequence of maps of groups or sequence of arrays, with XSLT 2 you could use a wrapper element to store groups.

Comment: I am using <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">

Comment: @teall, using `for-each-group` which was introduced in XSLT 2 but claiming to use XSLT 1 doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how you could number all subgroups sequentially while also keeping all their parent group counts:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <group>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>b</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>b</category>
        </item>
    </group>
    <group>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
        </item>
    </group>
    <group>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>b</category>
        </item>
    </group>
</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <xsl:variable name="categories" select="distinct-values(group/item/concat(category, '|', generate-id(..)))" />
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="group"> 
            <group group-num="{position()}" count-categories="{count(distinct-values(item/category))}" count-items="{count(item)}">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="category">
                    <category category-num="{index-of($categories, concat(category, '|', generate-id(..)))}" count-items="{count(current-group())}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="category"/> 
                    </category>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
             </group>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <group group-num="1" count-categories="2" count-items="5">
      <category category-num="1" count-items="3">a</category>
      <category category-num="2" count-items="2">b</category>
   </group>
   <group group-num="2" count-categories="1" count-items="2">
      <category category-num="3" count-items="2">a</category>
   </group>
   <group group-num="3" count-categories="2" count-items="3">
      <category category-num="4" count-items="2">a</category>
      <category category-num="5" count-items="1">b</category>
   </group>
</output>
```

If each group has its own distinct categories, then this could be simplified further.